# how to import millions of users without compromise sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, sidekiq

I have a rake task like this

```
task import_all: :environment do
  Person.find_each do |p|
    UserWorker.perform_async(p.to_global_id)
  end
end
```

each user creates around 20 new jobs on Sidekiq and these 20 jobs also create more 4 or 5 new jobs.
Turns out I have 980k users and my redis is using almost 70% of CPU usage, enqueing more than 7 million jobs!
How can I import all these users without compromise CPU/Mem?

Comment: What is this worker doing?

Comment: basically, instantiate a class called `NewUser`, fill data from `Person`, save and start workers that create `Interaction` and `InteractionObjects` from this Person interactions. We are migrating data to a new modelling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're spawning a background worker for every `Person`, why not spawn one?

```
# some rakefile I'm guessing?
task import_all: :environment do
  UserWorker.perform_async
end

# UserWorker.rb
class UserWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  def perform
    Person.find_each do |p|
      # whatever you were doing in here before...
    end
  end
end
```

Unless you have a massively parallel backend, there's not much advantage in breaking the work up into single workers.  You'll want to handle/log errors in here as appropriate and possibly re-try those individually but the general solution shouldn't need such fine-grained workers.

Comment: I'm also having a lot of timeout erros on `UserWorker`. These jobs retry themselfs. how can I do this using this solution?

Comment: You need to find out why and where you are having timeouts first, hard to generalize a solution without that info.

Comment: Hmm...got it. I'll see what I can do and change

Comment: Having one worker here doesn't leverage the power of concurrency. You might as well run it in line.

Comment: Indeed, for such a huge task I question whether Sidekiq is just adding complexity to an administrative task...

Comment: See my answer, you want to manage memory of redis, just limit the queue size to what sidekiq is going to handle.

Comment: I got it @dandlezzz but that may not help me right now. Actually, Nick Veys, I used your solution (partially) and I ended up finding a bug on my code hahahaha, but your idea is right